# Is there a way to specify the Encryption Key (AWS KMS Key) individually for each Database that is created in the AWS RDS DB Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-rds, amazon-kms

Example: I create an AWS RDS Instance: **myInstance1** with a KMS Key (Encryption Enabled)
Now, I create 3 databases under the RDS Instance : myInstance1.

```
DB Instance: myInstance1        -> KMS Key: UberKMSKey1

   Databases in above instance: myDb1   -> KMS Key: Key1 ????
                                myDb2   -> KMS Key: Key2 ????
                                myDb3   -> KMS Key: Key3 ????
```

Is the above scenario possible as far as the KMS key goes that each database under a DB instance has different KMS keys ?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you are only able to encrypt the whole RDS, and not individual tables.

Answer (score 1):

The KMS encryption is at a lower layer than what you hoping for.  In RDS, the KMS key is protecting the EBS storage that RDS itself uses to provide the RDS service.  This ensures that all data at rest is encrypted (at the disk level), but it is way below the layer it would need to be to protect specific databases inside the RDS instance.

TL;DR no.